# карусель на почтовом сервере

Tags: php, email, exim4

есть адрес `no-reply@domain.com`, если написать на него, то отправится шаблонный ответ с информационным текстом.

так получилось, что какой то подобный адрес (с автоответом) отправил письмо на этот ящик и они начали стремительно заполнять почтовый ящик обмениваясь этими письмами. так же может получиться если отправить письмо на несуществующий адрес, только переписка уже будет со своим `Mailer-Daemon@mail.domain.com`.

пытался исправить проблему кодом подменяя отправителя:

```
$headers = "From: Автоответчик <no-reply-to@domain.com>";
```

а при обработке письма с такими получателями сразу удалять. не помогло, сообщения о недоставке почему то всё равно возвращаются на `no-reply@domain.com`.

почтовый сервер exim4.

каким образом можно фильтровать подобные письма, побороть эту проблему? хоть программным способом, хоть расширениями или чем то ещё.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как у вас там все устроено, но если вам нет необходимости получать/читать то, что приходит на адрес `no-reply@domain.com`, то заверните "ящик" для no-reply@domain.com в /dev/null.

Comment: у нас сделано так что любое письмо на .*@dimain.com отправляется в ящик support@domain.com, php работает с письмами на основе получателя, и когда он встречает получателя no-reply он отправляет ответное письмо с информацией и удаляет само письмо. если отправленное письмо не дойдёт до получателя, то от почтового сервера придёт ответное письмо, на которое php так же ответит и удалит. только таких писем приходит слишком много и из за этого забивается почтовый ящик

Comment: *когда он встречает получателя no-reply он отправляет ответное письмо* — начните с удаления этой хромой логики. письма, пришедшие на адрес «не для ответов», должны попадать в /dev/null. ну, если очень хочется, можно их как-нибудь обрабатывать. но уж точно не надо **отвечать** на них. p.s. а тех альтернативно одарённых *манагеров*, которым вообще приходит мысль задействовавать почтовые авто-ответчики, в аду будут жарить на особо накалённых сковородках.